# How to Install Babylon on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Can someone please tell me how to install [Babylon Dictionary](http://www.babylon.com/) on Ubuntu? Babylon is only available for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Generally Windows software does not work on Ubuntu. You can try installing and running Babylon with [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) but the experience will be a different one.

Also here are some links from a quick google search (next time try it yourself):

http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/linux-and-unix/threads/96152/howto-using-babylon-dictionary-glossary-in-ubuntu

http://blog.shevin.info/2007/04/how-to-implement-babylon-dictionaries.html

http://lgjsheron.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/install-babylon-dictionary-glossary-in-ubuntu/

http://www.ehow.com/how_12120359_download-babylon-using-ubuntu.html

Comment: thnx for replying actually i did tried it myself and found no good answer thats y i came to this site to find some answer. but thnx anyway.